# Javascript not triggered

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, magento, magento2

I want to trigger the js function when the class subcat-tab is clicked, but it seems not to be working. I don't have any error messages but nothing is happening.

I'm under a `phtml` file from Magento 2.

```
<a href="#subcat_<?= $subcatId ?>" class="subcat-tab" title="<?= $subcat['label'] ?>" data-categoryid="<?= $subcatId ?>">

<script type="text/javascript">
    define([
        'jquery'
    ], function ($) {
        console.log("ok");
        $('.subcat-tab').click(function (e) {
            console.log(e);
        }
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `require` instead of `define` fix it somehow but don't really know why.

Answer (score 1):

Using `require` is the right approach when you initialize javascript in a template file.
`define` is used for javascript files in your web/js folders.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

replacing "$('.subcat-tab').click(function (e) {" with "$('.subcat-tab').on('click',function(e){"

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    define([
        'jquery'
    ], function ($) {
        console.log("ok");
        $('.subcat-tab').on('click',function(e){
            console.log(e);
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Actually my issue were I was using define instead of require.

Answer (score 0):

Use **require** in this case instead of define.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   require(
      [
        "jquery"
      ], function($) {
         console.log("ok");
         $('.subcat-tab').on('click',function(e){
            console.log(e);
         }
   });
</script>
```

Or use with define:

*1: create a new sample.js file:*

```
define(
      [
        "jquery"
      ], function($) {
           return {
              sampleClick: function(x){
                 console.log("ok");
                 $('.subcat-tab').on('click',function(e){
                      console.log(e);
                 }
              }
           }
   })
```

*2: calling in main file*

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    require(
       [
        "jquery",
        "sample"
       ], 
       function($, sample) {
           sample.sampleClick();
    });
</script>
```

[More information](https://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#jsfiles)